# Create a swing component that contain multiple component

Tags: java, swing

I try to create a component(Parent component) that contain 3 child component   `JLabel` for the name of field and `JTextField` and `JLabel` for the error of my field like this:

```
public class YLabel extends JPanel {

    public YLabel() {
        super();
        JLabel name = new JLabel("Some text");
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        JLabel error = new JLabel("Error text");
        super.add(name);
        super.add(field);
        super.add(error);
    }
}
```

So when I use this component I can't change the properties of the three component, I can just change the parent component `JPanel`

[image: MY Component]

Any idea how I can use this component and how I can change all the child components?

***EDIT***
[image: MY COMPONENT]

Comment: Make the fields attributes of the class, and provide get/set methods to change the content as needed. This is basic OO (that should be sorted long before trying to create GUIs - an advanced topic).

Comment: haha this work really good @AndrewThompson thank you very much, i work with Netbeans so i add my component in the palette and when i drag and drop my component i cant edit my child component like the other component, but i can edit them from my constructor, do you have any idea how i can edit them from the GUI? i will edit my question so you can understand more thank you another time

Comment: I use Netbeans (without the GUI designer) but don't provide support for it. As an aside: `JTextField field = new JTextField();` would better be something like (adjust integer to need) `JTextField field = new JTextField(8);`..

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Thompson so there are no solution for this problem?  ok i will work with your advice then :)

Comment: *"..are no solution for this problem?"* The concept of "I don't support Netbeans" is not the same as "there is no solution".

Comment: mmm, ok i understand @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this will help, but for some properties (I don't know how many?) if the child value is null the parent value will be used

For example:

```
JLabel label= new JLabel( "hello" );
label.setForeground( null );
label.setFont( null );
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
textField.setForeground( null );
textField.setFont( null );

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setForeground( Color.RED );
panel.setFont( new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 24) );

panel.add( label );
panel.add( textField );
```

For properties where this is not supported you would need to override the `setXXX(...)` method of the panel to update all its child components.

Edit:

So I assume you have a custom component something like this:

```
public class CustomComponent extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel heading = new JLabel(...);
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel error = new JLabel(...);

    public CustomComponent()
    {
        add( heading );
        add( textField );
        add( error );

        clearProperties( heading );
        clearProperties( textField );
        clearProperties( error );

    }

    private void clearProperties(JComponent component)
    {
        component.setForeground( null );
        component.setFont( null );
    }
}
```

Now when you use the component you can do something like:

```
CustomComponent component = new CustomComponent();
component.setForeground(...);
component.setFont(..);
```

Using this approach you don't have to override setForeground(...), setFont(...) of the panel to apply the attributes to each child component.

Comment: thank you @camickr this what i do in the first time but not helped me, my class extend JPanel so i use super to add the component, i don't return an JPanel, now the good idea is the idea of Andrew Thompson

Comment: @YoucefLaidani, ` my class extend JPanel so i use super to add the component,` - that doesn't make any sense. If you have a custom component you add the components directly to the panel. There is no need to invoke super.add(...). You have a design problem.

Comment: thank you @camuckr, maybe i misunderstood your answer :)

Comment: @YoucefLaidani `maybe i misunderstood your answer ` - see edit.

Comment: thank you @camickr for your answer this should help me i appreciate it really

Answer (score 2):

As per your scenario, you can retrieve the child components for the YLabel panel and then modify their properties, but then you need to remember the sequence of your child components. Below code for retrieving the child components

```
YLabel panel = new YLabel();
for(Component component : panel.getComponents()) {
    System.out.println("component "+component.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    //Change the properties here for your components
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a Source and Design button in your project, so when you select Design button, it lets you update properties of all objects. You have it?

Comment: thank you @Claudiu M but my component are in a jar, so did you think that is the only idea to solve this problem?

Comment: @Youcef Laidani, I had a project, where I wanted to use a jar for `Panel` class, just like you want to do. I wasn't able to modify child components, so I left that class included in my project folder and in main class I created an object of type `Panel` and worked with it. Each time when I needed to modify properties of `Panel` class, I was able to do it in design of `Panel` class

Comment: ok i understand @Claudiu M, thank you very much i will wait a little if nothing i will validate your answer